# Is there any open source program that use the inpout.dll?

Tags: c++, dll, import, parallel-port

Is there any open source program that use the inpout.dll to hook up the parell port and turn LED's on and off ive been looking for almost a whole month and havent found jack. I want to do this without any microcontrollers.

Answer (score 1):

These sites, http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm and http://lcdinterfacing.googlepages.com/, have some VB code for testing and using inpout.dll in real world scenarios, which you could probably tailor to C++.

[This site](http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/A_tutorial_on_Parallel_port_Interfacing.html), has a C++ tutorial on using it.

(* Strange, if you click on that link, you get a 404 but, if you then just hit ENTER in the address bar, it works - the address is:

```
http://logix4u.net/Legacy_Ports/Parallel_Port/A_tutorial_on_Parallel_port_Interfacing.html
```

if you want to cut and paste - it appears to be something to do with underscore/%5F translation *).

Note the comments that, if you're developing for the more secure Windows platforms (anything after Win98, I guess), you should be using the inpout32 variant.

Those links are good if you're just looking for source to be able to write your own. If, by open source, you actually meant 'speech-free', I haven't been able to find any (SourceForge, which is my go-to place for FOSS, returns zero hits).